# Can't remove Firebase AppCheck from Flutter project

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-app-check

I can't remove Firebase's AppCheck ([package](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_app_check)) from my Flutter project. I'm trying to remove it because all I get are errors like this while using it:

> 10.12.0 - [FirebaseAuth][I-AUT000018] Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: Error Domain=com.firebase.appCheck Code=0 "(null)"

I've added it properly, enabled it properly in the Firebase Console, enabled App Attestation in Xcode (testing on iOS), etc. But, with it not working I need to remove it.

So far, what I've tried doing to remove it are:

1. Removing the AppCheck package by removing `firebase_app_check` from my `pubspec.yaml` and running `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get`.
2. Removing all reference in the code to the package like:

```dart
 await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    webRecaptchaSiteKey: 'recaptcha-v3-site-key',
    androidProvider: AndroidProvider.debug,
    appleProvider: AppleProvider.appAttest,
  );
```

3. Attempted to remove it from the Firebase Console, but can't figure out how, so, I've unregistered the tokens.

However, even after all these steps I can `cmd + f` for "appcheck" in my project and get tons of hits signifying it still exists.

How can I fully remove it?

Thanks.

**Reponse to @Frank van Puffelen:**

I'm using the [firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) package as well in my code, and that works totally fine (login, signup, password reset, logout, etc.). It *seems to* have no correlation to the errors I've gotten via AppCheck. Thus, there's no definitive "code that fails" that I can see, it's just the seemingly arbitrary "Error getting App Check Token..." message I posted. Sometimes I don't get the message for periods of 5 or 10 minutes where everything is working, but I always revert to getting those exact error messages eventually.

Comment: Regardless of the error message you posted, does the authentication code actually work? If not, can you show the code that fails?

Comment: In Firebase Console, if you open `App Check`, under `APIs`, you can click on the components and there is an `Unenforce` button. Have you tried this?

Comment: @PeterKoltai I've navigated to Firebase Console > App Check > APIs tab > but there is no `Unenforce` button, or anything that looks similar. I just have a list of greyed-out options (storage, RTD, authentication, custom backend, etc.) but I can't interact with them.

Comment: It is strange. How did you enable it?

Comment: @PeterKoltai I clicked "Get Started" after clicking on "AppCheck" from the sidebar initially, then registered my device's KeyID, TeamID, and P8 Private Key. Since then, I've spammed random character in for the KeyID and TeamID to try to "unregister" my device (since it doesn't allow for deletion). Nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to just be to wait.

About a day after removing Firebase all the errors disappeared.